# JavaScript test fails in Visual Studio 2012 test explorer but succeeds in resharper

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, chutzpah

I've come across a very annoying problem writing my JavaScript test for the present project I'm in.

Chutzpah Test Adapter for Visual Studio 2012 is installed (uninstalled and installed once a again)

All other JavaScript tests runs smoothly except one (the reason why I'm asking for help here)

The JavaScript tests succeeded if I run them in Resharper, but when I run them in Visual Studio 2012 test explorer one of them as mentioned above) won't succeed.

I've debugged the whole code, restarted Visual Studio, restarted my computer, deleted my project and downloaded it again from our Team Foundation Server, I also deleted and created new a workspace, but nothing helps, this is really frustrating. I've search all over internet but haven't found anything or anyone who stumbled upon this problem...

the build is fine and the application runs perfectly...

If you have any idea why this one doesn't work, pls let me know!

Comment: Can you post the test & error?

Comment: If you cannot post the source code here, please consider submitting it privately at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio